# Finding the basis for the eigenspace corresopnding to eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with finding the basis of an eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue below :

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & -3\\
    -6 & 3 & -4 \\  
    6 & 0 & 7 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\lambda = 3$

**What I tried:**

I subtracted $A - 3\lambda$ as I recall doing for other problems and got the matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    -5 & 0 & -3\\
    -6 & 0 & -4 \\  
    6 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
.

Then, I row-reduced the matrix to get the system of equations

$-3x_1 - 2x_2 = 0$

$4x_1 + 3x_2 = 0$

$3x_1 + x_2 = 0$

I'm not so sure what to do next. The answer is $\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\  
    0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Check your row reduction, seems a bit fishy.

Comment: I disagree with your row reduction

Comment: No I still don't see why the eigenvector is what I see. I see that x1 = 0 from the first line, x3 = 0 from the second line, and x3 is free from the third line ?

Comment: But doesn't the second row tell us x3 = 0 ? Because if we write the RREF as an augmented matrix, there would be an additional 0s column to the right ?

Comment: Also if x3 = 1, then wouldn't that result in <0, 0, 1> instead of <0, 1, 0> ? thanks

Comment: thank you, this makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A-3I)\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix}
    -5 & 0 & -3\\
    -6 & 0 & -4 \\  
    6 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0$

$-5x_1 -3x_3 = 0\\
6x_1 + 4x_3 = 0$

I am ignoring the middle row, because it it pretty much redunant.  Row 2 = - Row 3.

Now take $6\times$ row 1 and add it to $5\times$row 2.

$2x_3 = 0$

and substitute

$x_1 = 0$

$x_2$ is free to be what it needs to be.

$A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} = 3\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

You have found 1 eigenvalue and one eigenvector for the eigenvalue associated with it.  What are the other eigenvalues?

By inspection looks like $1$ is an eigenvalue.

$(A-I) = \begin{bmatrix} -3&0&-3\\-6&2&-4\\6&0&6\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} -3&0&-3\\-6&2&-4\\6&0&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf 0$

expand out the linear equations

$x_1 = -x_3$

And substitute:

$-6x_1 + 2x_2 +4x_1 = 0\\
x_2 = x_1$

$\begin{bmatrix} -3&0&-3\\-6&2&-4\\6&0&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf 0$

and

$\begin{bmatrix} -2&0&-3\\-6&3&-4\\6&0&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

Last eigenvalue...
The sum of the eigenvalues equals the trace of the $A.$
$-2+7+3 = 1+3+\lambda_3\\
\lambda_3 = 4$

Also useful to know the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant of $A.$

I am going to let you find the vector associated with that eigenvalue.